# Polymorphic template container: shared_ptr vs reference_wrapper

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, reference, smart-pointer

Assuming we have two classes:

```
class A
{
    ...
}
class B : public A
{
    ...
}
```

Would it be better to write

```
std::deque<shared_ptr<A> > container;
```

or

```
std::deque<reference_wrapper<A> > container;
```

to create a container which is able to contain references to both of these classes and why?

In my case, the class containing the container wouldn't care, if a reference somehow became invalid.

However are there any caveats to take into account, when choosing one approach over the other?

Comment: It depends on the lifetime of the objects being stored in the vector. Shared_ptr isn't a silver bullet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my opinion on the matter:

1. consider whether both variants can actually be used in your case.  `reference_wrapper` is, by design, not default-constructible. That means you will not be able, for example, to call `container.resize()` when using the reference wrapper.  A `shared_ptr`, on the other hand, is default-constructed to an invalid/NULL state.  So, for some use cases, you *can't* use a `reference_wrapper`.  To give some examples:

   ```
   int i = 42;
   std::reference_wrapper<int> iref(i);             // OK
   std::reference_wrapper<int> uninitialized_iref;  // Not OK, but OK with shared_ptr

   iref = 23;                     // Not OK, but OK on a "normal" reference
   int& iref2 = iref; iref2 = 32; // OK
   static_cast<int&>(iref) = 23;  // OK
   iref.get() = 23;               // OK

   std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int> > irefs; // OK
   irefs.resize(10);    // Not OK!
   irefs.resize(10, i); // OK
   ```
2. The above examples already hint at something else: Usability and readability. Depending on your use case, you have to decide whether you prefer pointer-style notation (`shared_ptr`) or more-or-less-reference-style notation (`reference_wrapper`) and whether that makes the code more maintainable.  Personally I value this aspect quite highly.
3. As pointed out in a comment to your question, the object lifetime also plays a role.  When the container's lifetime is intended to exceed the lifetime of any of the referenced objects, you *have* to use `shared_ptr` (or maybe find a different system design).  With references you need to be certain about the respective scopes.  I also suspect that in your specific case, you *should* actually care about references becoming invalid -- if that can happen, you'd be in trouble, and it would usually be difficult to debug.
4. Storing `shared_ptr` elements of course implies that the values you want to refer to are *already* stored in shared pointers.  You can not create a shared pointer referencing an element created by some other means.  So, if you need to refer to *existing*, *non-shared* elements, you can not use `shared_ptr` and would have to go with `reference_wrapper` or plain old pointers.
5. As far as performance goes, I would not expect much of a difference. `reference_wrapper` usually uses a pointer internally, and the overhead for a `shared_ptr` is usually negligible.

All in all, I would base my decision around (a) my concrete use case, and (b) usability/maintainability/readability of the code using the container.

Comment: About your 4th comment: We can always create a shared_ptr from raw pointer like so `shared_ptr<classA> shared_ptr(raw_ptr);`, so I'll have to disagree.

Answer (score 2):

It's mostly a question of lifetime and ownership.  A container using `reference_wrapper` doesn't own its objects or manage their lifetime, a container using `shared_ptr` does.

If your container shouldn't own its objects, then use `reference_wrapper`.

If it should own its objects, then I'd take a third option. [Boost.Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) has template classes such as [boost::ptr_deque](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_deque.html) that store polymorphic types and manage ownership themselves, without the overhead of `shared_ptr` or the awkward syntax of having to dereference `shared_ptr` for each element.

Answer (score 2):

### The question is one of ownership

You make no mention of who owns the objects going into the container. Since the `shared_ptr` is an option, there is probably some form of shared ownership and dynamic storage allocation. **A clear definition of who owns the objects and how they are observed (i.e. who can observe them) will frame much of the implementation**.

> In my specific case, the class containing the container actually wouldn't care if a reference somehow became invalid.

The container is playing an observer role.

> However there might be a more generalised answer and a 'rule of thumb', when one should use one approach over the other.

Given the semantics of the the `reference_wrapper` there is a reasonable expectation that the object being referred to is valid whilst the `reference_wrapper` is valid. In your case this may not apply, but in general this is true and any maintenance done on the code at a later date may well assume this.

### Rule of thumb

Allow the lifetime of the shared ownership objects to be managed with a `std::shared_ptr` and use the "observer" `std::weak_ptr` in the container.

If the lifetime of the objects is not shared and somehow tied to the lifetime of container itself (via automatic storage duration), then the `reference_wrapper` is viable (in a similar way it could even be a raw pointer).